# gcc for ARM refuses to include Newlib standard directories

Tags: c, gcc, arm, header-files, include-path

I am trying to cross-compile with `arm-none-eabi-gcc-9.2.x` and had the following problem:

```
undefined symbol 'PRIu64'
```

(message shortened to necessary minimum by me) which was caused by the Newlib header `inttypes.h` doing a:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

which motivated gcc to include its onboard `stdint.h` from

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include
```

instead of the Newlib one in

```
/usr/include/newlib
```

thereby breaking the compilation with the above error.
Of course I first tried to prefix the include path search with the usual

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc-9.2.1 -I/usr/include/newlib ...
```

but to my big surprise gcc spew it back at me (via `-xc -E -v`) with:

```
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/newlib"
   as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
```

Only a

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc-9.2.1 -isystem /usr/include/newlib ...
```

convinced it to include the Newlib directory in its search.

Is this due to a broken installation? And how dare gcc to *not* include a path I am supplying?

Do the ARM people ship their [gcc](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) with both, Newlib and a set of vanilla gcc system headers or where did this misconfiguration come from?

Comment: stdint is part of the C language and comes from the compiler as the compiler authors choose what the C language variable types (long, short, int char) sizes are not the C library or anyone else.  So newlib cant possibly know, you had better be using the compiler supplied one in some way.    gcc, any particular prebuilt by anyone have nothing to do with newlib, that is like asking do "honda people" all use goodyear tires (two independent products that take a third party to combine).  Newlib can certainly add more stuff, but the core C language sizes are compiler specific by definition.

Comment: @old_timer I wasn't clear enough in that I also think this constellation to be "a bit" off the standard tracks, to put it mildely. However, the ARM gcc toolsuite has such an enormous user base that I hoped to receive more clarification on why this particular deviation from the usual procedures was chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, newlib provides `<stdint.h>` while gcc also provides it. So, when `<inttypes.h>` includes `<stdint.h>` it does not include `<stdint.h>` from newlib but the one from gcc. It wouldn't be a big deal if `<stdint.h>` wouldn't define some macro used internally by `<inttypes.h>`.

The best thing to do is to fix newlib, change your compiler or patch your system headers.

If it is not possible you can include `<sys/types.h>` before `<inttypes.h>`. `<sys/types.h>` includes `<_stdint.h>` that define the necessary macros.

It seems the problem is specific to arm-none-gcc provided by Debian:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=953844

Comment: "fix newlib": is it really recommended practice to meddle around in a 3rd-party lib of this rank and importance? The principle-of-least-surprise makes me hesitate...or did you address this to the newlib maintainers?

Comment: In fact, after having read the Debian bug report, I am not sure that the problem is on the newlib side.